# Custom tableview cell with 6 imageviews

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview, core-data

I have a very difficult problem. This is how my custom cell looks like.

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                                          |
|                                                                          |
|  Imageview1   Imageview2      Imageview3     Imageview4    imageview5    |
|                                                                          |
|                                                                          |
|                                                                          |                      
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I have a core database with 20 images. What I want to do is to fill up all these imageviews with my images. So at the and I should have 5 rows with in each imageview a different image.

Here is my code for my cellforrowAtIndexpath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        float xCoord = 0.0;
        Team *team = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:team.image]];
        UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
        UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(xCoord,0,imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
        xCoord += imgView.frame.size.width;
    }


    return cell;
}
```

This is how far i got. I don't now how to fill up this tableview correctly. The other imageviews are name img_Player2,img_Player3,img_Player4,img_Player5.

Can anybody help?

Thank you

**SCREENS WITH WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE**

[This](http://www.flickr.com/photos/74322780@N08/8050170687/) is what I want to achieve:

And at the moment I have [this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/74322780@N08/8071984693/in/photostream).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `UIImageViews` to the `contentView` of the `UITableViewCell`. Let's assume your 5 images are loaded in an `NSArray` called `imagesArray`. For simplicity I'm assuming each of your images is 64 (320/5) pixels wide and 44 pixels high.

Your code inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should roughly look like this:

```
float xCoord = 0.0;
for (UIImageView *imgView in imagesArray)
{
    [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(xCoord,0,imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
    xCoord += imgView.frame.size.width;
}
```

Your code will be this:

```
float xCoord = 0.0;

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    Team *team = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:team.image]];
    UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
    [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(xCoord,0,imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
    xCoord += imgView.frame.size.width;
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer. So don't work with a custom tableview ?

Comment: mm the images are displaying all below each other and overlapping each other. I updated my code

Comment: Yeah, I just gave you an overview. You have to modify the code to suit your needs. The images are overlapping because for every new cell, you are fetching an image from Core Data.

Comment: Wait I will provide some screens in a second.

Comment: also you need to clean cell.contentView, because you are using cell reusing.